# YII URLManager for RESTfull API

Tags: yii, url-routing

Trying to work on a RESTfull API with yii (being the first project using yii)

Having problem with getting URLManager to properly route calls:

```
    'urlManager' => array(
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'caseSensitive' => false,
        'rules' => array(
          'api/<controller>' => array('api/<controller>/list', 'verb' => 'GET'),
          'api/<controller>' => array('api/<controller>/create', 'verb' => 'POST'),
        ),
    ),
```

Tried working with this (this is not the full snippet, I had dispatchers for PUT/DELETE etc..
But it did not work... Being desperate, I tried even something as simple as that:

```
    'urlManager' => array(
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'caseSensitive' => false,
        'rules' => array(
            'tezt' => array('landing/beta', 'verb' => 'GET'),
            'tezt' => array('landing', 'verb' => 'POST'),
        ),
    ),
```

whenever I remove one of the rules, it works, but when I put both the rules in, none of them works, I get exception
    exception.CHttpException.404

```
 exception 'CHttpException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request
 "tezt".' in /yii-1.1.10/web/CWebApplication.php:280
```

Been banging my head agains this for 2 days now. Probably seen all the samples and tutorials on URLManager on the web (although could not find a straightforward and complete explanation of the rules). But, no joy.

Am I doing something wrong? Is it my box setup maybe?

Answer (score 7):

I tried this and it worked:

```
'rules'=>array(
            //API URLs
            array('api/<controller>/index', 'pattern'=>'api/<controller:\w+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            array('api/<controller>/create', 'pattern'=>'api/<controller:\w+>', 'verb'=>'POST'),
            array('api/<controller>/view', 'pattern'=>'api/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            array('api/<controller>/update', 'pattern'=>'api/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'PUT, POST'),
            array('api/<controller>/delete', 'pattern'=>'api/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'DELETE'),
            //Other URLs
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
```

"api" is a module configured in `modules` section as

```
'api'=>array('defaultController' => 'default',),
```

In REST client, you have to specify controller name, even for default controller.

I am using Yii 1.1.10 but I think Yii supports RESTful URLs since 1.1.7.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
'api/<controller:\w+>' => array('api/<controller>/list', 'verb' => 'GET'),
```

is api a module?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who stumbles on this, it didn't work because the rules were declared using the same keys, so the latter rule overrode the former.

In the future, declare the pattern in the rule configuration array:

```
array(
    'route',
    'pattern' =>'somePattern',
    'verb' =>'...',
),
array(
    'another/route',
    'pattern' =>'anotherPattern',
    'verb' =>'...',
),
```